# Insertion of linked list elements in interval tree

Tags: c++, c, tree, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have created an interval tree by making use of struct. There are keys to be inserted in the list .The definitions are

- l - lower limit
- u - upper limit
- h - height of tree
- top -head of the linked list. 
  Left and right point to the left child and right child respectively.

  ```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  #include<math.h>    
  struct list{
      int data;
      struct list *next;
  };

  struct node{
      int l,u,h;
      struct list *top;
      struct node *left,*right;
      };
  int lower[100],upper[100],size;
  struct node *root;
  }
  ```

I have tried doing it in two ways. The first one is below, 'i' is the element to be inserted. I have created a copy of the head of linked list and stored it in 'a'.I go on till I find the NULL pointer and at that point I insert 'i' and then copy value of a in head->top.This results in segmentation fault.

```
void insert_interval_tree(struct node *head,int i)
{
    if(i<(head->u) && i>=(head->l))
    {
        struct list *a=head->top;
        if(head->top==NULL)
        {
            head->top=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
            head->top->data=i;
            head->top->next=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            while(head->top->next!=NULL)
                head->top=head->top->next;

            head->top=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
            head->top->data=i;
            head->top->next=NULL;
        }           
        head->top=a;
        return;
    }
    else if(i<(head->l))
        return insert_interval_tree(head->left,i);
    else
        return insert_interval_tree(head->right,i);
}
```

The second method which also resulted in Segmentation Fault was , I made a separate function to insert element of list at the tail. Each time we want to insert any element, I make a call to this function.

```
void insert_list(struct  list *head,int i)
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        head->data=i;
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(head->next!=NULL)
            head=head->next;
        head->next=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        head->next->data=i;
        head->next->next=NULL;
    }
}
void insert_interval_tree(struct node *head,int i)
{    
    if(i<(head->u) && i>=(head->l))
    {
        insert_list(head->top,i);
        return;
    }
    else if(i<(head->l))
        return insert_interval_tree(head->left,i);
    else
        return insert_interval_tree(head->right,i);
}
```

The tree is generated by an array of intervals input by the user in sorted order. Here is the function used to build the tree

```
struct node * create_interval_tree(int start,int end)
{
    struct node *head=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node ));
    head->l=lower[(start+end)/2];
    head->left=NULL;
    head->top=NULL;
    head->u=upper[(start+end)/2];
    head->right=NULL;
    head->h=0;
    if(((start+end)/2)-start>0)
        head->left=create_interval_tree(start,(start+end)/2-1);
    if(end-((start+end)/2)>0)
        head->right=create_interval_tree((start+end)/2+1,end);
    return head;
}
```

I am not understanding where segment fault is occuring in both the cases described above. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. That looks like C, but contains not recommended style. Pick one language!

Comment: Please don't name any variable `l`. It's hard to tell `l` from `1`, and 'l' from 'I'. Use meaningful names. Will you know what `l,u,h` are in 6 months time? They are not commented, so you had to explain them.

Comment: 'I am not understanding where segment fault is occuring in both the cases described above' - maybe you should ask your debugger - it's sure to know.

Comment: @MartinJames  People think I never debugged the code and simply posted it on a programming platform for some guy to comment sarcastically about me

Comment: @user3600483 ' People think I never debugged the code', well, I cannot see any evidence of testing/debugging results/conclusions in your post.  Maybe you just forgot to copy them in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both methods, you call `insert_interval_tree(head->left,i)` without checking that `head->left` is not NULL. Same with `head->right`. This means that `insert_interval_tree` gets called with `head==NULL`, and it is not checked there. This is why it crashes.

There are other errors. For example, in the second method, inside `insert_list` you modify `head`, but `head` is not passed as reference, so this doesn't have any effect except for allocating memory that is never freed.

If you want to pass `head` by reference, declare the function as follows:

```
void insert_list(list *&head,int i)
```

Comment: You are right. I started to check where the  program crashes by using print statements after each line. Even though what you suggest is true, in the first case my program was not crashing when children were NULL but it was crashing at this statement head->top=a . But I am not understanding why? It would be great if you suggested something about this.